# How do you match patterns from an Attribute value to the recipe "only_if" or "unless" using ruby regex pattern?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

How do you match patterns from an Attribute value to the recipe `only_if` or `unless` using ruby regex pattern?

I am trying to match the result of `rpm -qa | grep #{rpmpackage}`

Comment: You say you want to use an attribute value, but then give a command to run. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to check if rpm is installed and if not you want to install it:

Some example:

```
rpm_installed = "rpm -qa | grep -q '^runit'"
cookbook_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/runit-2.1.1.tar.gz" do
  source 'runit-2.1.1.tar.gz'
  not_if rpm_installed
  notifies :run, 'bash[rhel_build_install]', :immediately
end
```

For you next question your can use `:upgrade` to Install a package and/or ensure that a package is the latest version without removing each time the package before, and also you can use `allow_downgrade true` for Downgrade a package to satisfy requested version requirements.

Example of remote file with mysql rpm files:

```
%w{
        mysql-community-common-5.7.16-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
        mysql-community-libs-5.7.16-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
}.each do |pkg|
        remote_file "/tmp/#{pkg}" do
        source "https://install.mysql.com/#{pkg}"
        end

       rpm_package pkg do
        source "/tmp/#{pkg}"
        action :upgrade
       end

end
```

If it does not works try to use `allow_downgrade true` with `action :install`, you you do not need to remove the rpm package each time, `allow_downgrade true` should work.

```
%w{
        mysql-community-common-5.7.16-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
        mysql-community-libs-5.7.16-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
}.each do |pkg|
        remote_file "/tmp/#{pkg}" do
        source "https://install.mysql.com/#{pkg}"
        end

       rpm_package pkg do
        source "/tmp/#{pkg}"
        action :install
        allow_downgrade true
       end

end
```

Comment: Thanks @Berlin. I was also looking at the part if I will remove the installer after install. The guard not_if works but what if the source url for example (in your case cookbook_file) in the attributes.rb file has been change, how would the chef resource detects it?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, what do you mean with if the `source url` has been changed ? do you mean the `rpmpackage` ?

Comment: I am not using cookbook_file resource, instead remote_file, the source package installer comes from the web. That param we have is that after the package has been installed, the resource will not run again right? but what if I want to change the version of the package? it means i need to change the remote_file or source URL. When that happens, the chef resource will no longer run until we remove the package from the system.

Comment: i hope i understood correctly, please check my answer now.

Comment: I will try that, then add the guards "not_if" to rpm_package resource right? or else it will keep looking the package and try to install

Comment: Chef should verify if a package is installed, and not loop again and again and again if the package already installed, but you can try using `not_if`, check the examples I gave and let me know if it works.

Comment: also please consider to upvote my answer if it helps :)

Comment: Yep it helps, your answers are definitely good. There some exceptions though, like installing Virtualbox rpm. rpm_package resource fails to run maybe because of some library dependencies.

Comment: seems to me it should be a new and different question if you have failures during installation because library dependencies and things like that.